# Toggling multiple audios by a toggle button with Jquery

Tags: jquery, audio, togglebutton

I would like an audio bar which would play and pause when clicked on the play icon, but when clicked on the toggle button on the right hand side (please see screenshot for reference) another audio should be played while pausing the first one.

[image: Screenshot]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var voice= $('.flix-sound-playpause');
    var audio1 = $('#flix-sound1');
    var audio2 = $('#flix-sound2');
    var audioID = [audio1, audio2];
    var toggleButton = $('.flix-controls-toggle-label');

    voice.on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('active');

        if(voice.hasClass('active')){
            audioID[0].trigger('play');


            $('.flix-controls-toggle-label').on('click', function () {  

            if(voice.hasClass('active')&&toggleButton.hasClass('active')){
                audioID[0].trigger('pause');
                audioID[1].trigger('play');



            } else {
                audioID[1].trigger('pause');
                audioID[0].trigger('play');

                } 
        }); 
      } else {
            audioID[0].trigger('pause');

        }
    });

});
```

Tried to implement, but its leading to callback hell as expected.

Comment: `please see screenshot for reference` firstly, what screenshot? Secondly, showing us the actual HTML code is far more effective.

Comment: this is my first time asking question here.. not quite sure how it works :) 
Anyways, check here http://prntscr.com/qs75p2